# Origin of 220-250V distribution standard

Tags: history, incandescent

While many countries in the world supply "domestic use" electricity at 220-250V AC, there's not much information of how that standard came to be. The history articles usually stick to Edison origin stories of 110V standard.

From what I can gather, 250V came as the highest voltage still usable with practical metallic filament incandescent lamps (whereas the voltage standards circa 110V owe their emergence to carbon filament lamps.)

It would be nice to read some real research on the topic, if such exists.

In a question form: Why was the 220-250V standard selected for domestic distribution? Why not go higher or stay lower (anywhere between that and the Edison's ~100V level?)

Comment: Wikipedia quotes some lines from book by T. P. Hughes, but he, in turn, simply quotes a book by Conrad Matschoss, which appears to be not available anywhere. Considering the importance of the topic I somehow expected it to be better documented. :-)

Comment: The thing is this; it's only an important topic if you are interested in the history of how the present-day voltages came about. For an EE designing stuff, it may be of some personal interest but, for doing his or her job, it is of little importance. Given also that there are systems all over the world ranging from below 100 volts to above 250 volts, there cannot be any physically strong reason for aiming for anything particular in that range.

Comment: Nevertheless, there are stories like Japan transition (started, then stopped midway) or USSR one (started and completed despite massive investment in the 127V grid). Enormous capitals are at stake, well being of entire nations, and yet, "not important". :-)